# Asp.net mvc 3 ctp  create SQL Server Express data file in  App_Data folder

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-server-express

I spent few days to create SQL Server Express database in `App_data` folder.
It always creating database in default location.

I have following connection string in my web.config file. data file created in default location.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PersonDBContext"
          connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=Customers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Persist Security Info=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />       
  </connectionStrings>
```

Is there a working sample code available for this?

-sr

Solution:

After posting this message I changed my connection like this:

```
<connectionStrings> 
   <add name="PersonDBContext"
        connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerInfoDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Customers.mdf;User Instance=true"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

my data file creating in project `app_data` folder.

Now my question is, I want to deploy this code in my production server, what is the best way to move this data file to prod server?

Do I need to install SQL Express on production server?

Thanks

-SR

Comment: What exactly is your question here? A sample code available for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Now my question is, I want to deploy
>   this code in my production server,
>   what is the best way to move this data
>   file to prod server?*

Best way: install some form of SQL Server (Express or another edition) on your production server, and copy your MDF/LDF files to the server and attach the database; use a server-based connection string for accessing your data.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="PersonDBContext"
        connectionString="Server=YourServerName;Database=Customers;Integrated Security=True;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />       
</connectionStrings>
```

If it's on a server - don't use the `AttachDbFileName=..../User Instance=True` kludge....

> *Do I need to install SQL Express on
>   production server?*

You need **some** edition of SQL Server on the server - doesn't matter whether it's SQL Server Express, or any of the other editions (Standard, Web, Enterprise).